# C# how to check if generic arguement is a real type?

Tags: c#, generics, types, reflection

**Hello,**

I have a code like the following:

```cs
IEnumerable<Type> types = new []
{
    typeof(MyService),
    typeof(ILogger<MyService>),
    typeof(ILogger<>),           // <-- that are the interesting lines
    typeof(IDictionary<,>)       // <-- that are the interesting lines
};
```

Now I want to filter all types, where the generic argument is not set

```cs
types
    .Where(t => t.IsGenericType is false || t.GetGenericArguments.All(at => /* is argument type a real type? */))
    .ToArray();
```

As shown in the example I have troubles to figure out if a type is just a placeholder or it is a real type.
I found it could work by proofing `string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.FullName) is false` but I think it´s not a really beautiful solution.
There must be something better.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

While writing the question I found the solution.

Just check `IsGenericTypeDefinition` instead of `IsGenericType`.

```cs
types
    .Where(t => t.IsGenericTypeDefinition is false)
    .ToArray();
```

I hope it helps someone! :D

Comment: What's wrong with `!t.IsGenericTypeDefinition`? It's a good old-fashioned `bool` with an intuitive name, no need for circumlocution. One of these days someone will write `is not true` and *really* grind my gears...

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the `!` notation. But in my opinion `is true/false` is also very readable and I like it. That´s why I use it. :)  
`is not true` is a valid if working with `bool?` instead of `is false || is null`